# Запись индекса самой большой температуры

Tags: python

Имеется файл с температурами и нужно создать массив из положительных температур,и во второй файл написать полученный индекс + 1.

У меня где то есть ошибка.

Вот код:

```
with open("entry.txt") as f:
    line = f.readline()
    line[-1].split()
    m = line.split()
    i = [0, ]
    n = 0
    for n in m:
        if int(n) < 0:
            i += n
    z = max(i)
    with open("exit.txt", "a") as e:
        e.write(str(i.index(z) + 1))
```

entry.txt это файл с температурами,exit.txt файл индекса + 1.

Напишите пожалуйста где ошибка или напишите исправный код.

Буду благодарен.
PS:Извиняюсь за столь грязный и ужасный код

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, пример входных-выходных данных.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
def main():
    with open('entry.txt') as f:
        s = f.read()

    all_t = map(int, s.split())               # [-20, 10, 30, 50, -13]
    t = list(filter(lambda x: x > 0, all_t))  # [10, 30, 50]

    i = t.index(max(t))                       # 2
    result = str(i + 1)                       # '3'

    with open('exit.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write(result)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```